# linked list c losing head address

Tags: c, linked-list

I'm implementing a "car fleet" management tool. For start, I declared a "Car" struct:

```
typedef struct Car{
    char ID[9];
    struct Car* next;
} Car;
```

My fleet will simply be a linked list of cars. I begin with an empty head, and add links to it via add_car function.

```
void add_car (struct Car* cars_fleet){
     struct Car* car = malloc (sizeof (car));
     scanf("%s",car->ID); 
     car->next = NULL;

if (cars_fleet == NULL){
    printf ("creating new list\n");
    cars_fleet = car;    
}

else {
    printf ("appending\n"); 
    Car* tmp = cars_fleet;
    while (! (tmp->next == NULL))
        tmp = tmp->next;
    tmp->next = car; 
}
}
```

And this is my main program:

```
int main(){
Car* cars_fleet = NULL;
add_car(cars_fleet);
}
```

Now, for some reason, my program treats all links as if they were the first one. I assume this is happening because of wrong memory allocation, perhaps at "cars_fleet = car". Any hints, tips or solutions? 
 thanks.

Comment: Formatting/indentation:(

Comment: 'add_car(cars_fleet);' cannot possibly modify cars_fleet since it passed by value.

Comment: so what would be the correct syntax here? if fleet is a pointer, and add_cars recieves a pointer to car, why can't I change the fleet's address? perhaps i should malloc the new car inside the first IF clause?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing the pointer by value. So any change in function void add_car (struct Car* cars_fleet) has no effect outside the function. You need to change function prototype :

```
void add_car (struct Car* cars_fleet)
```

Like this:

```
void add_car (struct Car** cars_fleet)
```

Then use, inside the function :

```
*cars_fleet = car
```

While, in main, call:

```
add_car(&cars_fleet);
```

Comment: yes, this works. could you help me understand why this syntax works?
cars_fleet is a pointer, so why is it important so send its address, and why do I have to use 2 "*" in the prototype?

Comment: In the initial protype of your fonction, cars_fleet pointer was a copy of the pointer you defined in main, so you were modifying a copy in the fonction. In the new protype I submitted, it is the address of the pointer defined in main that is passed to the fonction, and by using *cars_fleet = car, you modify this pointer.

Comment: `fonction` --> `function`, and  there is no concept of passed by value or passed by reference in C, all is passed by value ;)

Comment: @Alter: you're right, intentional missuse of language to make OP understand the difference between value and address of the pointer

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning to a local variable in `add_car`, change to:

```
Car *add_car(void){/* Car *x = malloc(...); ... return x */};
```

And in `main`:

```
Car* cars_fleet = NULL;
cars_fleet = add_car();
```

> How am I supposed to iterate through cars_fleet's links if I do not
>   pass it to add_car? and whose address am i returning? the address of
>   the new cars_fleet with the car added?

In your question you are passing a `NULL`, so there is no chance to iterate throug links, divide, use a function to get a fresh node and another one to insert this new `Car` in the list (passing the tail).

Comment: How am I supposed to iterate through cars_fleet's links if I do not pass it to add_car? and whose address am i returning? the address of the new cars_fleet with the car added?

Comment: thank you for answering. however, it does not solve my problem. i know it is possible to add links to an empty list, i was just missing some pointer basics. the anser above does that. again, thanks anyway.

Comment: You are welcome, notice that `malloc` can fail, dividing allows you to use code like `if x = add_car() then append_car(tail, x) else raise error`